# How I click a table row that have a check box and when you reaches the last table row button select change to unselect

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have table that have checkbox and button out side the table that will toggle from select to unselect , how do I click anywhere on the table row and my checkbox tick regarding where I will be selected one by one and when it reaches the last table row my button change from select to unselect, I did manage to click the table row  and checkbox tick , what I'm failing is when I reach the last table row and button change from select to unselect.

I have tried to get the length of row

```js
$('tr').click(function(event) {
  var $target = $(event.target);
  if (!$target.is('input:checkbox')) {
    var select_chk = document.getElementById("button1");
    $(this).find('input:checkbox').each(function() {
      if ((this.checked)) {
        this.checked = false;
        button.value = "Unselect"
      } else {
        this.checked = true;
        button.value = "Select"
      }
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="check" value="Select" />
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Surname</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>Cliff</td>
      <td>Deon</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>52</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>Dennis</td>
      <td>Van Zyl</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>25</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I made a snippet. I removed the invalid `</input>` too

Answer (score 0):

There were several issues.

Here is a working version that also handles clicking the button

I count the number of checked checkboxes are equal to total number of checkboxes.

I added an ID to the tbody

Also I use [ternaries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```js
const $select_chk = $("#check");
const $table = $("#tbl")
const $checks = $table.find('input:checkbox')
const checkLength = $checks.length;
$table.on("click","tr", function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches("[type=checkbox]")) { // if not a checkbox
    $(this).find("input:checkbox").click()    // click it anyway
  }  
  $select_chk.val(checkLength === $table.find('input:checkbox:checked').length ? "Unselect" : "Select");
});
$select_chk.on("click", function() { // we need function to get "this"
  const chk = this.value === "Select"; // check if text is select
  $checks.each(function() {
    this.checked = chk;
  });
  $select_chk.val(chk ? "Unselect" : "Select"); // toggle the text
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="check" value="Select" />
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Surname</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbl">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>Cliff</td>
      <td>Deon</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>52</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>Dennis</td>
      <td>Van Zyl</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>25</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank for you effort what you code does it doing what i what but i want to click anywhere on the table and check box tiick and when i reach to the last row select button change to unselect

Comment: Fixed. See update

Answer (score 0):

```js
//button click
$('#check').click(function(e) {
    if($(this).val()=='Select'){
        $('td input:checkbox').prop('checked',true);
        $(this).val('Unselect');
    }else{
         $('td input:checkbox').prop('checked',false);
         $(this).val('Select');
    }
});

//checkbox change
var $checkboxes = $('td input[type="checkbox"]');      
$checkboxes.change(function(){
    var countCheckedCheckboxes = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
    if(countCheckedCheckboxes==$('td input[type="checkbox"]').length)
    {
        $('#check').val('Unselect');
    }
    else{
         $('#check').val('Select');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="check" value="Select" />
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Surname</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbl">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>Cliff</td>
      <td>Deon</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>52</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>Dennis</td>
      <td>Van Zyl</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>25</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```